# Automatic resizing of graphic in Qualtrics to participants' screens?

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking to model something akin to [mousetracker](http://www.mousetracker.org/) where survey-takers choose between one of two options. I have the actual mousetracking code figured out. My issue is with creating an image that participants can choose between. If I make it too small, there will not be much variability between choices. If I make it too large, participants with small screens will have to scroll to see both images and the point of the survey will be moot.

Is there any way to code in CSS or Javascript for the image to stretch to fit its respective browser/screen? I have found code on this to work for the background, but unfortunately that will not work because there will be a series of different pictures.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can set maximal width/height of the image using vh/vw [units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). 1vh is 1% of the height of the viewport (browser window) and 1vw is 1% of the width of the viewport.

Example:
CSS: `.fit {max-height: 60vh;}`

HTML: `<img class="fit" src="x">`

(You can find how to add own CSS in Qualtrics [here](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/look-feel/advanced-look-feel-settings/).)